# How to use Multiple conditional statement in python

Tags: python, pandas

Having 2 columns where i have to update the third column based on the conditional statement between 2 columns. How i can use the same , i have tried but the case is not working.

We need to check for the condition if Col1 is having value but col2 is blank.

**Input Data:**

```
col1      col2         col3

azb225   AS277
Dzb555   
NZb777   NZb777
ZQS285   
NBC605   NZ3385
```

**Output Expected:**

```
col1      col2         col3

azb225   AS277        Available
Dzb555                Not Available
NZb777   NZb777       Available
ZQS285                Not Available
                      Available
NBC605   NZ3385       Available
```

**code i have been using :**

```
df['col3']=df.apply(lambda x:'Not Available' if (x['col1'].notna().all(axis=1)) and (x['col2'].isna().all(axis=1)) else 'Available',1)
```

But the above code is not working in this case.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#if empty strings instead missing values
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
print (df)
     col1    col2
0  azb225   AS277
1  Dzb555     NaN
2  NZb777  NZb777
3  ZQS285     NaN
4     NaN     NaN
5  NBC605  NZ3385

df['col3']= np.where(df['col1'].notna() & df['col2'].isna(), 'Not Available','Available')

print (df)
     col1    col2           col3
0  azb225   AS277      Available
1  Dzb555     NaN  Not Available
2  NZb777  NZb777      Available
3  ZQS285     NaN  Not Available
4     NaN     NaN      Available
5  NBC605  NZ3385      Available
```